# openssl Error Stack error : 03000086: digital envelope routines :: initialization error

Tags: node.js, webpack, next.js, node-modules

```
 opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
 library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
   }

  Node.js v19.5.0
```

i am getting this error in my nextjs project.

i don't want to downgrade my nodejs software version.  Is there any other solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are likely getting this error because you're using, (or one of the dependent packages is using) `Webpack` with a version of less than 5.

To check this run to check the Webpack version:

**npm**:

```
npm list webpack
```

or **yarn**

```
yarn list webpack
```

An example output could be. In this example I have Webpack 5 installed. But one of the dependency packages I'm using still has a reference to Webpack 4.

```
├─ vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder@2.1.1
│  └─ webpack@4.46.0
└─ webpack@5.88.1
```

The solution is to update the dependency package to the latest one that uses Webpack 5.
If the dependency package's latest still using Webpack 4, then you might need to use install Node 16 instead.

Answer (score 5):

Already got this error in the past, the solution was to execute this:

```
npm install react-scripts@latest --legacy-peer-deps
```

Show more of your dependencies, if it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Just go to `package.json` file and add `--openssl-legacy-provider` to your start script like this:

```
scripts": {
  "start": "react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider start",
}
```

Then `npm start` will work. if you have build then build it again and then `npm start`.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to run this command in your terminal:

```
export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider
```